# Vertical align UL to top of div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, vertical-alignment

I have three ul's added to a footer within bootstrap columns inside a parent row element, and I've used `vertical-align:top` for a similar footer before, but can't use this here to align each `ul` to the top of the parent div. (It's added to `footer > row > .col > ul`)

Any ideas?

Codepen: https://codepen.io/nickwcook/pen/aJPGeJ.

HTML:

```
<footer>
  <row>
    <div class="col col-sm-3">
      <ul>
        <li>Quick Menu</li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-sm-3">
      <ul>
        <li>Recent Posts</li>
        <li><a href="#">Post One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Post Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Post Three</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-sm-3">
      <ul>
        <li>About</li>
        <li><a>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vel decore vidisse an, id simul quaerendum usu. Et vis nemore mandamus. Ei pri dicit erroribus splendide. Alterum perfecto reprimique et nec, diam dolorum posidonium qui ei.</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </row>
  <row>
    <p>Developed by <a href="#">My Name</a></p>
  </row>
</footer>
```

CSS

```
footer {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #212121;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}

footer>row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 30px 5%;
}

footer>row:first-of-type {
  justify-content: space-between;
}

footer>row>.col {
  text-align: left;
}

footer>row>.col>ul>li:first-of-type {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 12px;
}

footer>row>.col>ul {
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 0;
}

footer>row>.col>ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

footer>row>.col ul>li {
  margin: 15px 0;
}

footer>row>.col ul>li>a {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #a5a5a5;
}

footer>row>.col ul>li>a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

footer>row:last-of-type {
  background: #1f1f1f;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

footer>row:last-of-type>p,
footer>row:last-of-type>p>a {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

footer>row:last-of-type>p {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: #747475;
  font-size: 11px;
}

footer>row:last-of-type>p>a {
  color: #a5a5a5;
  text-decoration: none;
}

footer>row:last-of-type>p>a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: They look aligned to the top to me.

Comment: Like this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LWMrNe? change align-items to flex-start in  footer > row

Comment: Rachel S - They might look it because of the content, but they're not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're overriding the normal Bootstap row with flexbox, use the appropriate flexbox alignment..

```
footer > row
{
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    padding: 30px 5%;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/peqKbj

Comment: Yeah what's with that, some people. never get the  downvoting a correct answer